# Почему глинобитный?

Tags: этимология

О домах, построенных из глиняных кирпичей, говорят, что они глинобитные. Точнее, насколько я знаю, речь идет о саманных кирпичах (иначе называемых адоба), то есть, сделанных из необожженной и перемешанной с соломой глины.
Но почему надо говорить не глиняные дома, а именно глинобитные? Это как-то связано с технологией изготовления подобных кирпичей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильная технология важна в любом деле, в том числе и глиноБИТном.

> Глинобитные стены — Под этим названием разумеются стены строений, возводимые из глины или из земли, содержащей значительную примесь глины, частицы которой плотно соединяются между собой **посредством уколачивания или утрамбовки.** Иногда глина смешивается с соломой (саман) или вереском.
>
> Для возведения глинобитных, или глиномятных, стен необходимы формы, или ящики, состоящие из двух дощатых щитов, соединенных параллельно брусками. Длина таких щитов бывает от 4,5 до 6 метров.

http://www.brocgaus.ru/text/029/253.htm

Берут опалубку и набивают ее глиной.